# Single word to indicate a nonsense poem, a poem with invented words?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Is there any English single word that can be used to indicate a poem with invented words, like Jabberwocky? I am looking for a single word rather than a two-word expression like "nonsense poem", "nonsense verse". Also, it doesn't have to indicate necessarily a Limerick.

(Of course, should this word *not* exist, please feel free to invent one …)

EDIT: I have found that in Italian this is called "metasemantic poetry" which is not a single word but it sounds ok to me. However, apparently this expression is not used in English.

Comment: [Namárië](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Nam%C3%A1ri%C3%AB).

Comment: Vogon, perhaps?

Comment: «Namárië» could be an interesting new word for something similar - but the entire language is invented there. Doesn't «Vogon» refer just to "bad poetry"?

Comment: Second-worst in the universe! But it does seem to be made up mostly of made-up words (possibly in Vogon, possibly just nonsense words—but Vogon is an invented language, anyways).

Comment: Wasn't it the third worst? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Must it refer to only a poem? [*Amphigory*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/amphigory) is close, but more broadly applicable.

Comment: +1 «Amphigory» is a piece of nonsensical writing (but not necessarily it has invented words in it). I am thinking of a poem where the structure of sentences respects the grammatical rules of a language, sounds like that language, but is made up of invented words (it might even make you think that you understand its meaning - while you are obviously not).

Comment: Amphigory comes up as a synonym on searching 'nonsense verse synonym' in Google.

Answer (score 2):

How about Pseudolexipoesy? Although it's made up, people looking at it would be able to work out what it means.

Actually in Greek putting two or more words together to make a third (or more+oneth) is not making them up, it's parts of the language structure.

Comment: Or perhaps pseudolexipoem and pseudolexipoetry?

Answer (score 1):

[Doggerel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doggerel) fits, but covers more ground than just nonsense with invented words.